# How to find out insertion time of records in an oracle table

Tags: database, oracle, record

I have a table with about 50,000 records in my Oracle database and there is a date column which shows the date that each record get inserted to the table, for example 04-Aug-13.

Is there any way that I can find out what time each record has been inserted?
For example: 04-Aug-13 4:20:00 PM. (For my existing records not future ones)

I searched over the internet and find some results but none of them seem to be practical.

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle [`DATE` type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) stores dates with accuracy to the second, but the default date format is `DD-MON-RR`, which is accurate just to the day.

To see the times, format the date using [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions188.htm). To get the format you're looking for, do this:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(myDate, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS PM')
FROM myTable;
```

To show all dates in that format, without resorting to `TO_CHAR`, change the default date format:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS PM';
```

The date format setting will be in force until you change it back or until you log out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But unfortunately, we did not store time as well as date and now we need time too! We have just dates, like 08-Aug-13 but there is no time with it!

Comment: That's too bad - there's really no way to get the information then. If you're on Oracle 10 or above there's a pseudocolumn named `ORA_ROWSCN` that returns a *guess* (I'd say a wild guess) on when the row was last updated (updated, not created). It's often inaccurate but you can try; it's all I can think of: `SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) FROM myTable`. If you're very, very lucky you'll get decent results for some of the rows.